# How to understand the fen arguments of Chess.js

Tags: chess

I'm not asking for the chess notation. I'm asking for the use of the arguments given. I'm using `Chess.js`. And I want to know the use of the arguments given in `chess.fen()`.

Here's the fen without moves: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1`
and then move `e4`: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq e3 0 1`.

Now my question is what's the use of `KQkq`, `e3`m `0`, and `1`. I moved `e4` but why did it say `e3`? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument is the board itself with the first 8 characters being row 8, then row 7 and so on. KQkq means white king can castle king side, w king q side, b king k side and b king q side respectively. So if it says only KQ it means only white king can castle king and queen side, black has lost its casting rights. - is no one can castle.

e3 means that e3 is the enpassant square. So if black had a pawn on d4 he could take the e4 pawn e.p. and end up on e3 square. - means there is no enpassant possible square (no side made a double pawn push).

The last 2 numbers are half move and move counter, the first one used to keep track of 50 move rule.

Read more here if you are interested:
[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth–Edwards_Notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)